# No such element error: No element found using locator: By(css selector, button.src-component-launcher-WidgetLauncher-wrapper.u-is

Tags: iframe, protractor, cucumber

I have got into the frame but when I try to find an element, then I am not able to locate elements.

The code of the iframe tag looks like:

```
<iframe title="Opens a widget where you can find more information" id="launcher" tabindex="0" class="zEWidget-launcher zEWidget-launcher--active" style="border: none; background: transparent; z-index: 999998; transform: translateZ(0px); position: fixed; transition: opacity 250ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) 0s, top, bottom; opacity: 1; width: 113px; height: 50px; max-height: 551px; min-height: 50px; margin: 10px 20px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></iframe>
```

The code of the button looks like:

```
<button class="src-component-launcher-WidgetLauncher-wrapper u-isActionable u-textLeft u-inlineBlock u-borderNone u-textBold u-textNoWrap Arrange Arrange--middle u-userLauncherColor "><span data-testid="Icon" class="src-component-Icon-container u-userColor src-component-launcher-WidgetLauncher-icon src-styles-components-Icon-Icon Arrange-sizeFit u-textInheritColor u-inlineBlock  Icon" type="Icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 20 20"><path d="M11,12.3V13c0,0-1.8,0-2,0v-0.6c0-0.6,0.1-1.4,0.8-2.1c0.7-0.7,1.6-1.2,1.6-2.1c0-0.9-0.7-1.4-1.4-1.4 c-1.3,0-1.4,1.4-1.5,1.7H6.6C6.6,7.1,7.2,5,10,5c2.4,0,3.4,1.6,3.4,3C13.4,10.4,11,10.8,11,12.3z"></path><circle cx="10" cy="15" r="1"></circle><path d="M10,2c4.4,0,8,3.6,8,8s-3.6,8-8,8s-8-3.6-8-8S5.6,2,10,2 M10,0C4.5,0,0,4.5,0,10s4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10S15.5,0,10,0 L10,0z"></path></svg></span><span class="src-component-launcher-WidgetLauncher-label Arrange-sizeFit u-textInheritColor u-inlineBlock " data-testid="launcherLabel">Help</span></button>
```

I have tried to locate the button using the following code:

```
element(by.css('button.src-component-launcher-WidgetLauncher-wrapper.u-isActionable.u-textLeft.u-inlineBlock.u-borderNone.u-textBold.u-textNoWrap.Arrange.Arrange--middle.u-userLauncherColor'));
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before accessing any element inside you need to first switch to iframe.

```
browser.switchTo().frame($("#launcher").getWebElement())
```

Above code will switch the focus to iframe window. Now you can find the button using `by.buttonText()` or `by.partialButtonText()` locators.

```
element(by.partialButtonText("Help")).click()
```

Now you can change the focus to the original page using,

```
browser.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

Comment: Thanks this is working completely fine and I got knowledge about how to switch to the exact frame I want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are either missing the code to switch to the iframe first or the selector is not unique and its going into a wrong iframe. Suggest you to get the text and `console.log` it to see it is indeed the right iframe.

That said, following code works just fine. Its basically using the same locator as yours, but after shifting the focus.

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.sleep(5000);

browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.tagName('iframe#launcher')).getWebElement());
element(by.css('button.src-component-launcher-WidgetLauncher-wrapper.u-isActionable.u-textLeft.u-inlineBlock.u-borderNone.u-textBold.u-textNoWrap.Arrange.Arrange--middle.u-userLauncherColor'))
                    .getText().then((text) => {
                        console.log(text);
});
```

Reference : http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.switchTo

**UPDATE:**
iframes are tricky to work with in general. Even if they are used inside an angular page, the parent page angular has **no control** over content inside the iframe. Also, parent page load completion does **not** mean the iframe(s) are loaded. Updated the code to include those into consideration. Should just work fine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually I wanted to click on the help button. These whole information is about the website: https://v3.trueimpact.com/#/login. Please see the website and the button is on the right bottom corner.

Comment: @RAJKUMAR Updated the answer. In general, its a good idea to see what exactly protractor is dealing with at the time of an error. In this specific case you could have checked if the iframe is loaded or not. That would have given you the hint that the iframes are not loaded yet. `element(by.css('body')).all(by.css('iframe')).count().then((val) => { console.log("Iframes loaded : " + val)});`. The more we stay away to debug/probe page content, the more likely an issue becomes puzzling.